# Angular Material SASS Breakpoint Variables matching the CDK?

Tags: css, angular, sass, angular-material, angular-cdk

The Angular Material CDK has a [builtin breakpoints constant](https://material.angular.io/cdk/layout/overview).

Does Angular Material also have a SASS Map or variables that we can import that match the breakpoints provided in the CDK?

[Something similar to what is defined in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67090439/different-value-in-scss-variable-if-using-function-for-setting-value).

Comment: I had the exact same question. I found that Angular Material does have a few breakpoint vars used internally, but not exposed. I ended up going with one of [these](https://npmtrends.com/breakpoint-sass-vs-breakpoint-slicer-vs-include-media-vs-rupture-sass-vs-sass-mediaqueries-vs-sass-mq).